# Google Sheets table is not showing new lines "\n" correctly in App Script WebApp

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table, line-breaks

I have a simple WebApp for getting a table data in a Spreadsheet.

What's the problem is, I have **not getting Line Breaks** in WebApp

Actual Data in Spreadsheet

```
Akash
Bangalore
```

but getting like this in WebApp

```
Akash Bangalore
```

Pls help me to do this ..

[Spreadsheet URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/116XVmxdI5uQ4A2QsjLrI25pUQBCDL22KCkGXHZZfKVQ/edit#gid=0)

[WebApp URL](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwIjZPkPIjiONwUwA98tFAy_4iaKzyTyUEN3fFu_MWr3egIEJNdgqqJbFJF-SojDKE/exec)

Below is the **Code.gs** file

```js
function doGet() {
  template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index.html');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

  var spreadsheetId   = '116XVmxdI5uQ4A2QsjLrI25pUQBCDL22KCkGXHZZfKVQ';

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName("Sheet1") ;

  var dataValues = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues() ;
```

Below is the **Index.html** file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Display Google Sheet Web App</h1>
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin:auto"  cellpadding="5px" >
      <?var tableData = dataValues ?>
      <?for(var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) { ?>
      <?if(i == 0) { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <th><?= tableData[i][j] ?></th>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } else { ?>
        <tr>
        <?for(var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) { ?>
        <td><?= tableData[i][j] ?></td>
        <? } ?>
        </tr>
      <? } ?>
      <? } ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried replace(/\n/g, "<br />") but no use..

Comment: Where did you try that?

Comment: Tried in code.gs file,
var dataValues = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().toString().replace(/\n/g, "<br/>") ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New lines `\n` in html are ignored. To get breaks in html, you should use `<br/>`. Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop:

```
var dataValues = sheet.getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues()
    .map(row => row.map(value =>
          value.replace(/\n/g, `<br/>`)
        )
     );
```

Comment: Wonderful, worked very nice .. thank you so much @TheRealMaster ..

Answer (score 0):

When passing a value to be displayed, i.e. as `<?= tableData[i][j] ?>` instead of printing scriptlets `<?= ?>` use force-printing scriptlets `<?!= ?>`

The above because when using the first, Google use contextual escaping, while with the other Google will show the data "as is".